# Dr Who : The Doctor's Daughter - Why is Cobb the only old person

Tags: doctor-who

In the Dr Who episode “The Doctor's Daughter”, we see a bunch of young people fighting the Hath. Why is Cobb the only person that is old, considering that the war between Humans and Hath only began a short time ago according to Donna's calculations.

If each person has to be processed and they all are accelerated to be adults, then how did Cobb come to be so old? I don't think this was explained in the episode.

Comment: You're correct, I don't think it was addressed. Possible hypothesis: there was a fault with the age accelerator when he was cloned - either aging him past prime, or continuing to age him after completion. Or he had a premature aging disease.

Comment: "*Russell T Davies suggested in the podcast for the episode that, as well as creating a child from a parent, the machines could clone important figures. [General Cobb](https://tinyurl.com/ycz83o4z) could be the fifth Cobb of that week."*

Comment: I don't think they ever really explored the workings of the cloning machines themselves, but my internal reasoning was that it would accelerate the clones' ages up to the age they were when their original templates were mapped by the machines. So if, as a 20-year-old, you scanned yourself into the machine, it would make clones of 20-year-old you; but if you were 60, it'd make 60-year-old clones.

Comment: @Valorum kind of makes sense...

Comment: @Vanguard3000 kind of makes sense too, that would make Jenny to  be the same age as the Doctor.

Comment: @Pikachun who's to say she isn't? As a rule, the Doctor is always an exception to a rule. Even the aforementioned one. ;)

Comment: David Tennant is 13 years older than his wife-daughter, so clearly the cloning machine malfunctioned a bit when presented with TimeLord DNA. Not unsurprising, really, they are ludicrously complicated beings.